# Using `map` to solve 'FizzBuzz'

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

I tired to use `map` to solve fizzbuzz.

```
def fizzbuzz(n)
    array =(1..n).to_a
    array.map{|x| 
        if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
         x = 'FizzBuzz'
        elsif x % 3 == 0 
         x = 'Fizz'
        elsif x % 5 == 0
         x = 'Buzz'
        end
    } 
   array
end
```

Somehow, it doesn't work. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Show the error, or you cannot receive help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map!` as suggested by @tmc and some other changes try:

```
def fizzbuzz(n)
    array =(1..n).to_a

    array.map!{|x| 
        if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
         x = 'FizzBuzz'
        elsif x % 3 == 0 
         x = 'Fizz'
        elsif x % 5 == 0
         x = 'Buzz'
        else
         x = x
        end
    }

   p array
end

fizzbuzz(10) #=> [1, 2, "Fizz", 4, "Buzz", "Fizz", 7, 8, "Fizz", "Buzz"]
```

As you can see I've added a call to the method `fizzbuzz` with an argument of `10` which you can change. And I've used `p` to inspect the array as well as a final `else` statement.

Comment: You can rid of `x = ` and just have rest of expression - given that last executed statement is the return value.   Also, if you use just `array.map`, then, you don't need `p array`.  You don't need `array` variable itself - as you can do `(1..n).map`

Comment: @WandMaker I agree with you about your recommendations (although I'll leave it for the OP to sort out) except I can't see how the array gets returned or printed without `p` or similar?

Comment: No worries.  Array should be ideally printed by printing the result of `fizzbuzz(...)` method call.

Answer (score 4):

Method `map` does not change the original array. Use the bang version `map!` instead.